# How to display a number below each dynamically created images?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a particular image as many times as the number given by user.This part is accomplished. But i want to display a number below each image. For example if user input is 4, there should be 4 images with '1' below 1st image '2' below second. The image must also be clickable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new element to the array.</p>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="">
<button onclick="imag()">Try it</button>


<div id="demo">

<script>
function imag(c,x) {
var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
var c="<img src='C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/New folder/G.jpg'/>";
    
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    arr.push(c);
  
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.join("&nbsp&nbsp");

}
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the number you're looking for in your loop. So you can simply add it to your array like this.

JS:

```
function imag() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var c = "<img src='C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/New folder/G.jpg'/>";

    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        arr.push("<div class='image'>" + c + "<br />" + (i+1) + "</div>");
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.join("&nbsp&nbsp");
}
```

CSS:

```
div.image {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this gets the number on the right side of the image. it must come below the image

Comment: @mohit I edited my answer with some css to display the number below the image.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var imageSrc = "http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/148/1/9/20x20_PNG_Icons_DOMO_by_JMcIvor.png";

function imag(c,x) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.setAttribute("class", "container");
  
  for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("class", "image");
    image.setAttribute("src", imageSrc);
    container.appendChild(image);
    var text = document.createElement("div");
    text.innerHTML = i+1;
    container.appendChild(text);
    demo.appendChild(container);
  }
}
```

```css
#demo {
}

.container {
}

.image {
}

.text {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new element to the array.</p>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="">
<button onclick="imag()">Try it</button>

<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I just use another image url to test the code, replace it with your one. I hope this helps.